# Unable to correct Python 2.7 exception syntax

Tags: python

Running some code with Python3 reports the below error:

```
$ python3 report.py --regions ap-southeast-2 --file file.csv
  File "report.py", line 51
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Research indicates that this deprecated syntax. I have found conflicting information on how I may fix this.

I have tried to engage python3 syntax, which I believe would be to switch

```
   try:
        f = file(filepath, 'wt')
    except Exception, e:
        f = None
        sys.stderr.write ('Could not open file %s. reason: %s\n' % (filepath, e))
```

To:

```
  try:
       f = file(filepath, 'wt')
except:
       f = None
       sys.stderr.write ('Could not open file %s. reason: %s\n' % (filepath, e))
```

What happens then is that I get errors relating to the "e" being missing... so I'm unsure how best and easiest to resolve the syntax issues between the two versions. Can you help or advise? Thanks!

Comment: try `except Exception as e:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want a method that is compatible for both Python2 and Python3,

Then try something like this:

```
 import sys
 try:
    ### your filepath code goes here or any other code
 except Exception:
    tb, err = sys.exc_info()[:2]
    print(err)
```

Using `exc_info()` here is good as it provides you with a tuple of information on what the error and the traceback to that faulting code, specifically the `(type, value, traceback)`. In this case, you are getting back the traceback and the error (value).